# Parse and retrieve properties from ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a web application where I have a need to be able to access ViewState values and re-populate controls with these values. I want to utilize the existing hashed/stored ViewState values not create custom ViewState values.

How can I go about retrieving values/properties from a page's ViewState for specific controls?

Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following [Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) seems helpful. I really agree for the title "truly understanding ViewState"

there is a good example how you can inherit from webcontrols and access their props.

Comment: Thanks for the article. It is a lot of information to digest. I will read over it but in the meantime, does anyone have a short answer if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

short like this?

```
    private string GetValue
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.empty;

            if (ViewState["someID"] != null)
            {
                result = (string)ViewState["someID"];
            }

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["someID"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not setting these values, as I stated above. I am not creating custom viewstate values. I want to access the ViewState properties that are already automatically generated, for each control, throughout the lifetime of a page.

Comment: so you need somethings like enurate all viewstate values?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET already utilizes ViewState to persist control values and repopulate them after postback, so you shouldn't need to touch the ViewState if that's all you're looking for. If you need to store extraneous information in ViewState, you can get and set data in ViewState like you would any other key/value collection:

```
//store value in viewstate
ViewState["someValue"] = "Foo";

//retrieve value from viewstate
string someValue = ViewState["someValue"].ToString();
```

This above is just a simple example, but you can store pretty much anything in ViewState. That being said, you shouldn't use ViewState to store large objects like result sets, etc. ViewState is encoded and stored in the page, and large objects can quickly bloat the ViewState and degrade page performance, along with other adverse side-effects.

Comment: I am not setting these values, as I stated above. I am not creating custom viewstate values. I want to access the ViewState properties that are already automatically generated, for each control, throughout the lifetime of a page